# Is it possible to repair this flat bow?

Tags: archery, repairs, long-bows

Is there hope for a repair on this bow?

Samick Outlander American flat bow.

[image: bow inscription]
[image: split in the bow]

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no expert.  But every instinct in me is screaming to never trust this bow under tension ever again, not even to be strung.  It could make a nice piece of decor depending on your taste.

Comment: You'll probably have to talk to a dealer/manufacturer for that

Comment: How were you going to go about fixing it? How did it happen? If this happened due to dry firing the bow, then throw it away. That is just the visible damage. If this is something that has come over time, it *could* be fairly benign and something you can arrest with high strength glue and some scuba repair rubber (which is my goto fixer for everything). For certain, the bow might disintegrate on the next shot, but that is true for all bows.

Comment: no known reason for the break. certainly no dry fire as that would have ripped the users arm to shreds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes it is. Send Samick an e-mail ([here for the US](https://www.samickusaarchery.com/contact-us)) and explain your problem (with pictures) to them.

---

It is possible to repair this bow, but only by a professional. So either talk to the manufacturer (recommended) or a **professional** **(!)** bowyer.

The crack actually looks a little bit more horrible than it really is. Your bow (or 'modern bows' in general) are made from a stack of different materials like glas, certain kinds of wood and so on. The layers are basically really well glued together under high pressure.

What the bowyer needs to do know is just to repeat this whole process. Mainly they'll put in specialised glue, heat and pressure to get your bow up and running again.

And again, don't do this by yourself! Send it in. Also don't trust any hobby bowyer. If this is not repaired just perfectly it can get really really dangerous for you, the target (can be ignored if not hunting) and people standing beside.

Further information is provided within the comment section of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwBmE5IviXA). You can use [this link](https://dbase.tube/youtube-search-in-comments?v=dwBmE5IviXA&term=samick%20Samick) to find all the Samick related ones, like for example:

> 3 -4 month 55 lb samick sage bottom limb snaps after a session
>   shooting 20 arrow . Everything text book .. .. have to see what
>   happens